# What memory stick should I get for my XBox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, hardware

I recently got a new 4GB Xbox 360, and I wonder if I should get some more memory using a memory stick. Are these fast enough to store game data on or should they just be used for backup?

Are there any limitations on storage size, transfer speed etc?

Comment: BTW: USB 3.0 is not supported, so a USB 2.0 storage device is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB flash drives are fast enough to store data, and yes, there are limitations.

Using a compatible flash drive **over 1 GB**, you can reserve a **maximum of 16 GB** for *profiles*, *game saves*, and *downloadable content*. To use USB storage, you'll need to configure it first. Plug it in and go to System Settings, Memory, then select your device to start setting it up.

Supporting USB storage devices up to 16GB in size is a huge increase in storage over any solid state memory storage solutions currently available for Xbox 360. Users that need more storage have options in the Xbox 360 hard drives, which are available for purchase separately.

You may want to read the [official help page](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/storage) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One follow-up question: I also have a PS3. If I have a memory stick with 32GB, can I assign one partition to the xbox and one partition to the PS3?

Comment: I'm not sure if that can be done. I recommend you asking a new question about this. BTW, you're welcome.